# Video Format is not supported or source is unavailable. - Opera

Tags: video, opera, video-player

I'm trying to see a video in my Opera for Linux mint browser, but when I click the play button it appears the error "Format is not supported or source is unavailable." or something like that. I already tried the players of other sites, such as amazon prime and unity learn, on Firefox and it works perfectly.

My Opera version is Opera One version: 108.0.5067.40 and I'm using Linux Mint LMDE 6 Faye

Here's the error in the Unity Learn player: [image: Unity learn player error]